# Is it fine from the viewpoint of the security to set always `{ credentials: "include", }` in Fetch API of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Some HTTP request requires authentication, some requests are no, but if usage of `{ credentials: "include" }` is not the vulnerability, why not always keep `"include"`value?